# How "recompile" .fla to .swf with actionscripts

Tags: flash, actionscript

So I have a .SWF; lets call it 'OLD'.

I downloaded Sothink and was able to 'decompile' it to a .FLA that comes with Shape, Image, Font, Sprite, Frame and Action folders that have respective file types in each.

My main intent is to modify one actionscript (.as) file that is inside Action/com/'companyname'/controller/site/. So I go into Flash CC (creative cloud) and edit the one (.as) I am talking about and save the changes.

So now I want to 'recompile' and get a new .SWF that has the changed .as I made. So I go to (in FLash) Open>something.FLA.

Here is where the weird thing happens: the .FLA opens and all the other folders (Shape, Image, Font, Sprite and Frame) are there but Action folder. Despite that I go ahead and Publish.

The resulting .SWF appears, it has SOME actionscripts (when in Flash it showed NONE), but more painfully it doesnt have the .as I modified (or any other .as thats nested.

Am I doing this totally wrong? How should I do this properly? I just want to change the one .as file and I know exactly what change to make.

TIA

Comment: Update1: I have done a good amount of research here on SO and have done the following to no avail: 
Check the Class File designation
Explicitly added the paths of relevant .as 
Tried to compile using old (not decompiled) .fla

Comment: Update2: I may have found an old .fla (not decompiled) but it still wont compile with the relevant as! I dont know what gives. Im using Flash CC, could it be a quirk in this new CC suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I used Flash Pro CS6 instead of Flash Pro CC.

Wow...